# Java Socket TCP Maximum Segment Size

Tags: java, sockets, tcp

Is there a possibility to read out the TCP "MSS" option header of a Connections SYN packet or is this buried too deep in layers of layers of layers ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure the latter is the case. You're shielded against the workings of the TCP stack by a platform-independent layer. Doing otherwise would make Java less portable.

If you insist, you have the option of doing socket I/O via JNI.

Comment: Well, after more looking and reading I have to agree on the Layers upon layers thing, but the platform independence is depatable. I am explicitly opening a TCP socket so it should/could still be platform independent to read TCP specific settings, since none of them are platform dependent.

Although its probably a mess to implement on the JDK level

Comment: Agreed. The only other thing I can do to help you is upvote this interesting question. Good luck!